# Does PyS60 has a reliable garbage collection?

Tags: python, symbian, nokia, s60, pys60

I have heard it many times that garbage collection in PyS60 is not up to to the mark. This imposes a lot of limits on writing cleaner code. Can I at least rely that the non cyclic references are cleaned up after a function exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostly you can, but occasionally PyS60 needs a little "help". Unbind keys, always cancel timers, might have to manually delete some classes etc. Nothing too bad.

Btw current 1.9.x branch uses python core 2.5.4. In my opinion 1.9.5 is the first version, which might be better that 1.4.5. Worth taking a look, especially if you want to play with 5800 XpressMusic :)

Answer (score 3):

PyS60 as of version 1.9.0 uses Python 2.5.1 core and has no problems with garbage collection.